# passing event to nested function in React and didn't get the outer event value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing React which will take an value from input box, and pass to _.debounce function.

However, I am not able to read the input value inside the _.debounce function. I tried bind(this) but it didn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import _ from 'lodash';

const API_KEY = 'XXXXXXX.....';

export default class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            videos: []
        };

        this.handleChange();
    }

    handleChange = () => {
        console.log(event);
        _.debounce(() => {
            console.log(this, 'inside debounce');
            YTSearch({
                key: API_KEY,
                term: event ? event.target.value : '梁静茹'
            }, (videos) => {
                this.setState({ videos });
                this.props.getNewVideos(videos);
            });  
        }, 0)();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <input className='search-bar form-control' 
            value={this.state.term}
            onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the console output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that you are putting the event in a closure scope, and it's changing/getting cleaned up before the asyncronous call to `_.debounce` executes.

Try doing this:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  event.persist(); // <--- Add this line
  _.debounce(() => {
      YTSearch({
          key: API_KEY,
          term: event ? event.target.value : '梁静茹'
      }, (videos) => {
          this.setState({ videos });
          this.props.getNewVideos(videos);
      });  
  }, 0)();
    }
```

Read more on React's Synthetic Events and Event Pooling here, there is a note about async access to events at the bottom: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.